# What are Outlink categories of Wikipedia

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, wikidata, wikipedia

I am wondering if it is possible to view outlink categories of a given article in Wikipedia? For example, consider the Wikipedia article about 'Data Mining'. What are the outlink categories of "Data Mining" article and how to find them in the Wikipedia page?

According to the paper "Using Wikipedia knowledge to improve text classification
"; the outlink categories and their count of "Data Mining", "Machine Learning" and "Computer Network" are as follows.

[image: Outlink categories and their count]

However, I still could not discover how they obtained these outlink categories and their counts. Please help me.

Comment: *"The values correspond to the numbers of out-link articles which belong to the corresponding category"*

Comment: Basically, like [this](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=false&sameAs=false&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX+dct%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0ASELECT+%3Foc+(count(%3Foc)+AS+%3Fcount)+%7B%0A++++dbr%3ABusiness_intelligence+dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%2Fdct%3Asubject+%3Foc%0A%7D+GROUP+BY+%3Foc+ORDER+BY+DESC(%3Fcount))

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I would like to do this offline. Do you know which data dumps of Wikipedia I should download to facilitate this task?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Please let me know if you know an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869194/how-to-find-general-terms-in-wikipedia Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the list of linked articles, get the categories for each and sum up. If you want to do it with the official API in a single request (well, single sequence of requests because the data will be too large for one response so you'll have to use [query continuation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries), it would look like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=categories&titles=Machine%20learning%7CComputer%20network%7CData%20mining&generator=links&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=max&gpllimit=max

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I am not clear what that last url represent. Can you please tell me what that is?

Comment: It is a call the the Wikpedia API. Here's the [sandbox version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=categories&titles=Machine%20learning%7CComputer%20network%7CData%20mining&generator=links&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=max&gpllimit=max). It does all kinds of batching which makes it a bit complex. A less effective but simpler equivalent is for each article fetch all the links ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Machine%20learning&prop=links&pllimit=max))...

Comment: ...and then for each link fetch the non-hidden categories of the linked article ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=ACM%20Computing%20Classification%20System&prop=categories&climit=max&clshow=!hidden)).

Comment: thank you very much for the resources. I would like to perform this task offline. Can you please let me know what data dumps I should download to perform this task?

Comment: The minimum-effort version is downloading the SQL dumps for the [pagelinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table) and [categorylinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) tables.

Comment: One extra question, do you know how to get the wikipedia data dumps of disambiguation details. For example, the disambiguation page for the term “Puma” lists 22 associated concepts, from persons, to vehicles and sport clubs. Please let me know your thoughts?

Comment: The page_props dump can tell you which pages are disambiguation pages (you can probably use the categorylinks or templatelinks tables to the same effect as well). Beyond that, there isn't any easy way as far as I know - you'd have to do some lightweight parsing to locate all the bullet points on the page and then if they have multiple links hope that the first is the disambiguated page.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually my task is to check if a given wikipedia article contains any disambiguation pages or not? e.g., given 'Puma', it says return 'TRUE'. Can you please let me know an easiest way of doing it using the current dumps. I can ask this as a seperate question if needed.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the given article is a disambiguation page, or whether there is a separate disambiguation page corresponding to it?